# JPA convert Expression<Timestamp> to Expression<Calendar>

Tags: java, jpa, calendar, criteria-api

I am trying to do the following (cb = CriteriaBuilder):

```
cb.between(
    cb.currentTimestamp(), 
        kampanjeArtikkelPriser.get(KampanjeArtikkelPris_.overstyrtSalgsprisPeriodeFra), 
        kampanjeArtikkelPriser.get(KampanjeArtikkelPris_.overstyrtSalgsprisPeriodeTil)),
```

But I get the following syntax error:

> - Bound mismatch: The generic method between(Expression<? extends Y>, Y, Y) of type CriteriaBuilder is not applicable for the arguments (Calendar, Path<Calendar>, Path<Calendar>). The inferred type 
>      Path<Calendar> is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <Y extends Comparable<? super Y>>
>
>   - Bound mismatch: The generic method between(Expression<? extends Y>, Expression<? extends Y>, Expression<? extends Y>) of type CriteriaBuilder is not applicable for the arguments (Expression<Timestamp>, 
>       Path<Calendar>, Path<Calendar>). The inferred type Object&Serializable&Cloneable&Comparable<? extends Object&Serializable&Cloneable&Comparable<?>> is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <Y extends 
>       Comparable<? super Y>>

Would it be possible to convert Expression<Timestamp> to Expression<Calendar>? I seem a bit stuck since I have not found a way to do this, and as far as I am able to see there are not many other options for me either. Changing the entities java types is not an options since this is a somewhat big system, and I do not know what kind of impact that would have.

Comment: Did this option work, Lars?

Comment: Which option did you mean? It probably works to check for the date boundaries one at a time. In this case I had to give up on the Criteria API and use a native query instead because hibernate got it's parentheses wrong and thus also the result of the query.. :)

Comment: Is there no way to make a Path<Calendar> out of the cb.currentTimestamp()?

Comment: Maybe there is, but I haven't found one...

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a good option would be to do the following instead:

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
cb.and(
    cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(kampanjeArtikkelPriser.get(KampanjeArtikkelPris_.overstyrtSalgsprisPeriodeFra), now),
    cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(kampanjeArtikkelPriser.get(KampanjeArtikkelPris_.overstyrtSalgsprisPeriodeTil), now)
)
```

Comment: Leaving the question open in case someone finds a better solution - perhaps more readable.